# Using ActiveModel Dirty appropriately in a controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

A rails controller action has the usual boilerplate structure

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @individual.update(individual_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @individual, notice: "Individual was successfully updated." }
       # if @individual.changed?  
        render_pdf
      # end
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Howeve, the goal is to - where the record has been updated (aside from the `updated_at` attribute) - activate a method that will generate a PDF.

Consulting the documentation for [dirty](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html), I fail to generate a true response to the `changed?` method.  I suspect this is because of the timing of the method being invoked (`if @individual.update` implies the record is already saved and thus the dirtied bits cleaned up).

How should the above be written to achieve the goal?

*alternative*
a callback `after_update_commit` might be an option, however, the [rails guide is not explicit](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#aliases-for-after-commit) as to whether the action is launched when no attributes are updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rb
if @individual.previous_changes.present?
```

Comment: I had tried that with no success, but it got me to looking deeper.  I was editing a translatable field via Mobility gem... and Dirty obviously saw no change in the parent table.